# Failing to produce glmmTMB diagnostics plots with package DHARMa

Tags: r, diagnostics, glmmtmb

I have tried to produce diagnostics plots for `glmmTMB` models using package `DHARMa` without success. Example 1.1 in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/model_evaluation.pdf) gives:

```
owls_nb1 <- glmmTMB(SiblingNegotiation ~ FoodTreatment*SexParent +
                         (1|Nest)+offset(log(BroodSize)),
                         contrasts=list(FoodTreatment="contr.sum",
                         SexParent="contr.sum"),
                         family = nbinom1,
                         zi = ~1,
                         data=Owls)
plot(owls_nb1_simres <- simulateResiduals(owls_nb1) )

# Error in on.exit(add = TRUE, { : invalid 'add' argument
```

The same happens with:

```
if (!require(RCurl)) install.packages('RCurl'); library(RCurl)
unicorns <- read.csv(text= RCurl::getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcoplebani85/datasets/master/unicorns.csv")) 
# simulated data, obviously
unicorns_glmmTMB <- glmmTMB(Herd_size_n ~ food.quantity
                        + (1 + food.quantity | Locality)
                        + (1 + food.quantity | Year_Month),
                        family="poisson",
                        data=unicorns)

plot(simulateResiduals(unicorns_glmmTMB))
# Error in on.exit(add = TRUE, { : invalid 'add' argument
```

If I run the same model in `lme4::glmer`:

```
unicorns_glmer <- glmer(Herd_size_n ~ food.quantity
                        + (1 + food.quantity | Locality)
                        + (1 + food.quantity | Year_Month),
                        family="poisson",
                        data=unicorns)
```

...and "feed" it to:

```
plot(simulateResiduals(unicorns_glmer))
```

I obtain diagnostics plots without issues (by the way I am aware that model `unicorns_glmer` is suboptimal and can be improved).

I'm using:

- `glmmTMB` version 1.0.2.9000 freshly installed from github;
- `DHARMa` version 0.4.1;
- `R` version 3.6.3;
- MacOS Sierra version 10.12.6.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Does anyone know how to solve it?

---

***EDIT:** my question was originally on how packages `performance` and `DHARMa` handle `glmmTMB` objects. For the sake of focus and clarity I removed the references to package `performance`, thus making this question specific to `glmmTMB` and `DHARMa`.*

Comment: Is this in a *clean* R session? Example 1 is working fine for me with `DHARMa` 0.4.1, devel `glmmTMB` (I might not have the master branch installed; I will try again but I'll be surprised if that makes a difference). I have a devel version of R (4.1.0+), but again I'd be surprised if that matters. Best guess is that you have a variable defined in your environment that is somehow confusing `DHARMa` during evaluation.

Comment: ... when I try to run `performance::check_model(unicorns_glmmTMB)` I get "no applicable method for 'influence' applied to an object of class 'glmmTMB'"

Comment: I restarted R, made sure to wipe its memory with `rm(list=ls())`, and loaded `glmmTMB`, `DHARMa` and `performance`. Upon running the code above, I'm still getting the same mysterious `Error in on.exit(add = TRUE, { : invalid 'add' argument`. I then repeated the procedure but making sure that all the packages listed at the beginning of the vignette were loaded and the outcome was the same.

Comment: OK, I can at least see where the problem is (and that it's recent). The relevant code is here: https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/blob/master/glmmTMB/R/predict.R#L178-L185 .  Can you confirm that the problem goes away if you revert to the CRAN version of `glmmTMB`?

Comment: @BenBolker I confirm that when using glmmTMB 1.0.2.1 from CRAN DHARMa 0.4.1 deals with glmmTMB models without issues and `Error in on.exit(add = TRUE, { : invalid 'add' argument` disappears. Conversely an unrelated error (re-)appears:
`Error in .Call("FreeADFunObject", ptr, PACKAGE = DLL) : 
  "FreeADFunObject" not available for .Call() for package "glmmTMB"`
That’s simply because github issue #615 (https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/615) has been addressed on glmmTMB 1.0.2.9000 but hasn’t been addressed on glmmTMB 1.0.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a [bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17815) that was present in R <= 4.0.1. From the [R NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) for version 4.0.2:

> on.exit() now correctly matches named arguments, thanks to PR#17815 (including patch) by Brodie Gaslam.

I have attempted to fix the glmmTMB code so it works around the bug.

You could try

```r
remotes::install_github("glmmTMB/glmmTMB/glmmTMB@on_exit_order")
```

and see if that helps (provided nothing goes wrong, this branch should be merged into master shortly ...)

Comment: ...or I might just update R :-) The gremlins of the early R 4 versions put me off but I guess they've all been solved by now. Thanks for looking into it, I couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: `remotes::install_github` didn’t work (probably something to do with an issue with private packages) but `devtools::install_github` did, so I was able to test `glmmTMB@on_exit_order` with DHARMa 0.4.1 on R 3.6.3. It worked like a charm. No errors, no warnings, just pure graphics bliss. Thanks!